# Does anybody know how to load the frameanimation3d in ursina faster?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, panda3d, ursina

When trying to make an animation in Ursina Engine you can call a `frameanimation3d` function but it requires an obj file for each frame.
So if there are 100 .obj files to load, the game will be slower. Is there maybe a way to load all these files faster?

( Or maybe use `panda3d actor function`, but doesn't it support a certain type of file? )

Answer (score 0):

It is true, you can load animations faster with panda3d or ursina. If you are using panda3d, use their .egg file. You can improve performance by instancing and using LoD. Check the examples in Panda's Manual. Don't forget, ursina is built above panda3d, so you can use Panda's code in ursina.

P.S.: I'm not sure if Panda's actor supports LoD.

I wrote this in case if you are using the same model